# roslaunch: suppress summary

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm doing a project where I'm using roslaunch to run our software stack through several regression tests and each time I call roslaunch it prints out a summary with all the parameters loaded (there are dozens). This summary is getting in the way of parsing useful printouts from our nodes. Is there a way to stop roslaunch from printing out this summary or otherwise suppress the output while leaving node output intact?

```
started roslaunch server <>

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS  
 * /rosdistro: noetic  
 * /rosversion: 1.15.14
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409735/roslaunch:-suppress-summary/) by [Raika](https://answers.ros.org/users/28049/raika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2022-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-11-23**:
I've updated the title of your question, as the original title made it seem it was a duplicate of the many other Q&As which ask for "suppressing summary output" (such as #q349820).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a way to stop roslaunch from printing out this summary or otherwise suppress the output while leaving node output intact?

No.

`--no-summary` will suppress everything from the summary.

---

Edit:

> when I said node output I meant the printouts from the nodes themselves (with output=screen), not the list of nodes launched in the summary.

Ah.

In that case: `--no-summary` should do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raika](https://answers.ros.org/users/28049/raika/) on 2022-11-23**:
This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-11-23**:
I'm confused. `--no-summary` suppresses the summary completely, including the Nodes section.

**Comment by [Raika](https://answers.ros.org/users/28049/raika/) on 2022-11-23**:
Sorry, when I said node output I meant the printouts from the nodes themselves (with output=screen), not the list of nodes launched in the summary.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-11-23**:
Then technically, your question is a duplicate of #q349820.

But seeing as the title is different, I've not closed it as such.